# Python regex matching for multiline text

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have a log file with the below content

```
commit da83ddfdfb36f0c48ab2137efaa8c81a6bb41993
Author: ”abc <abc.def@zyx.com>
Commit: ”abc <abc.def@zyx.com>
..
..
```

I am trying to create regex matching expression as below

```
TEST_COMMIT = 'commit\ (?P<commit>[a-f0-9]+)\n(?P<author>Author.*)\n'
RE_COMMIT = re.compile(TEST_COMMIT, re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)
```

This matches fine on regex101 (https://regex101.com/) but does not work in my code.

I want to get the commit ID and the Author info as separate group expressions.
So

```
commit group should be : `da83ddfdfb36f0c48ab2137efaa8c81a6bb41993`
author group should be : `Author: ”abc <abc.def@zyx.com>
```

My python version is 2.7.12

Any comments on what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I have been able to resolve this issue.

The problem was that the logfile new line was carriage return + new line. \r\n

Once the Regex is changed to include \r\n its able to get the regex groups correctly. This code is working

```
TEST_COMMIT = r'''
commit\ (?P<commit>[a-f0-9]+)\r\n
(?P<author>Author.*)\r\n'
(?P<committer>Commit.*)\r\n'
(?<message>.*)\r\n
)
'''
RE_COMMIT = re.compile(TEST_COMMIT, re.MULTILINE | re.VERBOSE)

commits = RE_COMMIT.finditer(data)
```